# In `find`, after using a test like `-type d`, how can I at some point undo this setting, so the rest evaluates as if `-type d` wasn't there?

Tags: linux, find

When using the command `find`, I often need to have a flow control, e.g. if .. then.

A simplified example;

```
find ~ -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec echo -e "\nnext beg of new dir::" \; -exec ls -lad \{\} \;
```

The test `-type d` returns true if current file is of the type directory, thus I see blank lines and the notice that a dir follows.

Yet I want the next `-exec` to show the output of `ls` for each file, directory or non-directory.

Using the option `-o` before the second `-exec` is not the solution. That inverts the flow control, the files which are not directories are listed. Like if giving `-not -type d`.

A solution seems to be when writing both options, `-not -type d` and `-o`, like this:

```
find ~ -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec echo -e "\nnext beg of new dir::" \; -not -type d -o -exec ls -lad \{\} \;
```

Is this the official way to "undo" `-type d`?

Comment: If you do not care about soft links, block, character devices just use `-type f` (what is not dir is file)

Comment: == 13.12.2023 22:33 thanks and excuse me, that was my typo. I have forgotton to type "-type d" on both locations when I was typing my post by hand. Now what to do: if I edit and correct my post would be good for future readers, but your hint will become non-understandable. Regards

Comment: Don't worry. I have sorted this out.

Answer (score 1):

If your `find` is GNU `find` then it supports `-true` which always evaluates as true and `-false` which always evaluates as false. Then this is what you can do:

```
# with GNU find
find . -type d -exec echo DIR: \; -false -o -print
```

The first part is `-type d -exec echo DIR: \; -false`, it echoes `DIR:` iff the current file is of the type directory. The trailing `-false` *guarantees* this part fails; it will fail even if `-type d` evaluates to true. In other words there is no way for this part to succeed, because the only way for it to succeed is to evaluate `-type d` to true and `-exec echo DIR:` to true *and* `-false` to true. But `-false` cannot evaluate to true, ever.

The part preceding `-o` always fails, therefore `-print` will be evaluated for each and every file, as if `-type d` wasn't there.

POSIX-ly you can use `-exec false \;` for `-false` and `-exec true \;` for `-true`.

```
# POSIX-ly
find . -type d -exec echo DIR: \; -exec false \; -o -print
```

In this case you can avoid spawning `false` as additional processes. Use this trick:

```
# POSIX-ly
find . -type d -exec echo DIR: \; ! -type d -o -print
```

Again, the part before `-o` cannot be true (`-type d` and `! -type d` cannot both be true), this guarantees the desired logic. The snippet `! -type d -o` is equivalent to what you used in the question (`!` is a portable equivalent of `-not`), there is nothing wrong with it.

Note the trick requires you to negate some previous test, while `-exec false \;` is universal. `-false` is also universal but your `find` may or may not support it. If your `find` supports `-false` and if portability is not an issue, then just use `-false -o` as shown at the beginning of this answer; this is the simplest solution.

Comment: == 13.12.23 22:45 many thanks for your answer. You confirm that my logic was correct (which was my petition), and your "false" is better. Tanks and Regards.