# How to "find" while following specific symlinks on Linux?

Tags: linux, find, symbolic-link

I would like to `find` files (with similar feature to find), but follow and only follow specific symlinks (by pattern matching).

Apparently `find` itself cannot handle it: There is no option to setup symlink follow behavior; and a naive `find -L` easily live lock (or be extremely slow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last sentence of the question suggests the problem is not with following symlinks in general (and e.g. applying `-newer` to the symlink in one case, while to the target in another case), but with following symlinks *to directories* and thus descending where you don't want.

Per [specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/find.html), `find` shall detect infinite loops, so a livelock shouldn't happen. Resources (including time) being wasted may be a problem and I understand your concern.

First of all, use `-L` to allow `find` to follow symlinks you want it to follow. Then you need a way to detect other symlinks.

In `find -L` `-type l` is never true, but you can detect symlinks with `-exec test -L {} \;` (remember `-exec … \;` is also a test, it succeeds iff the inner command exits with status 0). This way you still can apply some test(s) specifically to symlinks and `-prune` (or not) accordingly.

For example the following command will descend only symlinks whose names start with `foo` or end with `bar`:

```
find -L . -exec test -L {} \; ! \( -name 'foo*' -o -name '*bar' \) -prune -o -print
```

Whatever expression you originally wanted, place it after `-prune -o`. In the above command the "original" expression is `-print`. Remember `-exec` suppresses the implicit `-print`, so if you need `-print` then add it explicitly (like we did).

Note that `-name` tests the name of the symlink itself. If you want to test the name of the target then you need `realpath`, possibly `basename` and some shell code; example:

```
find -L . -exec test -L {} \; -exec sh -c '
   case "$(basename "$(realpath "$1")")" in
      baz* ) exit 0 ;;
      *qux ) exit 1 ;;
   esac
   exit 0
' find-sh {} \; -prune -o -print
```

The above command will `-prune` any symlink to any file whose name starts with `baz`, but it will descend symlinks to directories with names ending with `qux` (unless starting with `baz`) and finally `-prune` all other symlinks.

Notes:

- `realpath` and `basename` are not portable.
- `realpath` resolves all symlinks.
- The behavior in case of a broken symlink may or may not be what you expect.
- Invoking a separate `test` for every file will hurt performance, but I have found no better way. Invoking `sh`, `realpath` and `basename` is also bad in this matter, but here it happens only for symlinks, so in the majority of cases the impact will be limited.
- `find-sh` is explained here: [*What is the second sh in `sh -c 'some shell code' sh`?*](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690)
- In the examples pathnames that get `-prune`d will not be `-print`ed. Change the final fragment to `-prune -false -o -print` and they will be printed. See [explanation](https://superuser.com/a/1820279/432690); a portable alternative to `-false` is there in case you need it.

Comment: `find` did seem to livelock in my test. `find / >/dev/null` takes ~10 sec, while `find -L $HOME >/dev/null` (which did detect some loop) cannot complete in 60 sec.